# Spring boot - @Autowired is not working on @Configuration class

Tags: spring-boot

I used `@ComponentScan` on the `Application` class and use the `@Configuration` on my config class, in my config class, I want to inject beans defined in other config class by using `@Autowired` annotation, but when I run the application, I got null for these fields.

```
@Configuration
public class AConfiguration {

     @Bean
     public A getA(){
         return ..;
     }
}

@Configuration
public class BConfiguration {

     @Autowired
     private A a;

     @Bean
     public B getB() {
        **something need a, but a is null**
     }
}
```

---

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class EhcacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }

}

@Configuration
@DependsOn("ehcacheConfiguration")
public class ShiroConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;

}

@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JarApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `AConfiguration` class using any beans from `BConfiguration`?

Comment: @KenBekov, No, AConfiguration don't using any beans from BConfiguration

Comment: Autowire `A` into the `getB` method instead of a member variable Spring is then better able to detect dependencies between classes. so write `getB(A a)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 @Configuration
    public class AConfiguration {
         @Bean
         public A getA(){
             return ..;
         }
    }

    @Configuration
    public class BConfiguration {

         @Autowired
         private A a;

         public B getB() {
            **something need a, but a is null**
         }
    }
```

Comment: I was careless. I had the @Bean annotation, I forgot when i edited the question.